# Process data in panda frame and replace nan with zero

Tags: python, pandas

I do have a spreadsheet file that I would like to process read some of the columns sequentially and perform some calculations per row. To make my life easier I will need to replace all the nan values with zero to perform the calculations. So my code looks like:

```
df = pd.read_csv('documents/doc.csv', error_bad_lines=False)

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if i==0:
        continue
    else:
        try:
            id_1 = row[0]
            var1 = float(row["first column"])
            var2 = float(row["second column"])
            var3 = float(row["third column"])
            var4 = float(row["fourth column"])
            var5 = float(row["fifth column"])
            
            if math.isnan(float(var4)) or float(var4) == 0: 
                final= round(0.25*(var1+ var2 + var3)/3 + 0.75*var5, 1)
                pdb.set_trace()
            else:
                final_grade = round(0.166*(var1+ var2+ var3)/3 + 0.33*var4 + 0.5*var5, 1)
                print (var4)
            
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            pdb.set_trace()
```

Whats the optimal way to extract my variables and replace all potential `nan` values with `zeros`?

Comment: add this after read_csv line:  df.fillna(0, inplace=True)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a special command for that in Pandas:

```
df = df.fillna(0)
```